# Fastest way to extract raw Y' plane data from Y'Cb'Cr encoded video?

Tags: python, c++, ffmpeg, video-encoding, yuv

I have a use-case where I'm extracting `I-Frames` from videos and turning them into [perceptual hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) for later analysis.

⠀

I'm currently using `ffmpeg` to do this with a command akin to:

`ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i 'in%~1.mkv' -vsync vfr -frame_pts true -vf 'keyframes/_Y/out%~1/%%06d.bmp'`

and then reading in the data from the resulting images.

⠀

This is a bit wasteful as, to my understanding, `ffmpeg` does implicit `YUV -> RGB` colour-space conversion and I'm also needlessly saving intermediate data to disk.

Most modern video codecs utilise [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) and have frames encoded in a [Y'C<sub>b</sub>C<sub>r</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr) colour-space, where **Y'** is the [luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) component, and **Cb** **Cr** are the [blue-difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-Y), [red-difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-Y) [chroma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrominance) components.

Which in something like `YUV420p` used in [*h.264*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding)/[*h.265*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) video codecs is encoded as such:

[image: single YUV420p encoded frame]

Where each **Y'** value is `8 bits` long and corresponds to a pixel.

⠀

As I use gray-scale data for generating the [perceptual hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptual_hashing) anyway, I was wondering if there is a way to simply grab *just* the raw **Y'** values from any given `I-Frame` into an array and skip all of the unnecessary conversions and extra steps?

*(as the [luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) component is essentially equivalent to the grayscale data i need for generating hashes)*

I came across the `-vf 'extractplanes=y'` filter in `ffmpeg` that *seems* like it might do just that, but according to [source](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/manipulating_video_colors/extractplanes.html):

> "...what is extracted by 'extractplanes' is not raw data of the (for example) Y plane. Each extracted is converted to grayscale. That is, the converted video data has YUV (or RGB) which is different from the input."

which makes it seem like it's touching [chroma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrominance) components and doing some conversion anyway, in testing applying this filter didn't affect the processing time of the `I-Frame` extraction either.

⠀

My script is currently written in `Python`, but I am in the process of migrating it to `C++`, so I would prefer any solutions pertaining to the latter.

`ffmpeg` seems like the ideal candidate for this task, but I really am looking for whatever solution that would ingest the data fastest, preferably saving directly to `RAM`, as I'll be processing a large number of video files and discarding `I-Frame` [luma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)) pixel data once a hash has been generated.

I would also like to associate each `I-Frame` with its corresponding frame number in the video.

Comment: Decent question, to my untrained eyes, but if I may make a recommendation? You should not ask for fastest because it is too mobile a target to make for a good Stack Overflow answer unless you get very specific in your hardware and system software. For example, fastest on a PC running Windows might be substandard on an ARM-powered Android device.

Comment: That's a fair point, this script is meant to be used as a small component of a larger system ran on a server using commodity x86 hardware, potentially without a GPU.

Comment: With 'fastest' here I simply mean 'least number of operations', as the the proposed ideal ingest solution pertains to knowing if there's a way to simply jump to and copy a specific portion of raw sequentially encoded frame data, rather than having to preform any kind of processing on it *(or having to grab the full frame)* first, I recon that there wouldn't be too many significant differences since it's just streaming data, and copying smaller amount of sequential data is probably faster than doing colour-space conversions and ending up needing to copy more *(sequential)* data.

Comment: That linked page is wrong. extractplanes simply copies out the component data. Any YUV->RGB conversion is performed on account of output encoder constraints. So, using rawvideo muxer and output only extracted plane.

Answer (score 0):

The linked page is not official documentation. "Each extracted is converted to grayscale." Well, yes. Cb plane only would be just grayscale and same for Y and Cb and also for R, G, B, A planes if they exist. Nothing is converted to grayscale, it is tagged as grayscale, because it is, as it is one plane, and that is grayscale.

"That is, the converted video data has YUV (or RGB) which is different from the input." It is different from YCbCr to RGB converted source. But the data is the actual underlying limited or full range data even for 30 bit files or 48/64 bit files.

"Since the example input is yuv420p format, that is, the chrominance components are thinned out." Well, yes. For 4:2:0 Y plane is full size while Cb and Cr planes are just 1/4 in size.

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#extractplanes

Also, see this bug (fixed): https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9575